# I cannot find bootstrap.css in my folders

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I can't find the path for my CSS documents.

My bootstrap.css is located at https://i.hizliresim.com/P7kRGO.jpg and here is the error message I get: https://i.hizliresim.com/7BgOQN.jpg

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Encode+Sans+Expanded:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link href=./plugin-frameworks\bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="../views/plugin-frameworks/bootstrap.css"rel="stylesheet">

<link href="./fonts/ionicons.css" rel="stylesheet">


<link href="/common/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I'm using PHP 7, Laravel 5.4, and running on xampp Apache.

Comment: Images aren't loading, attach them in the post instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use asset helper like this to link a resource in public directory:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('styles/main.css')}}">
```